# Using code block in ruby's if statement

Tags: ruby, regex, if-statement, codeblocks

is there a way to pass a code block as a ruby if condition?

I have a list of regular expressions and I want to check if a message matches any of them and then do something accordingly or else do something different.

Here is an example snippet for how I think it should be written:

```
msg_values.each do |msg|
    if (SKIP_MSG_ARRAY.each { |regular_exp| return true if msg.match(regular_exp)})
        # do something
    else
        # do something else
    end        
end
```

is it possible? or else what is the best way of writing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enumerable#any?`. See the reference docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html. This method (as well as `Enumerable#all?`) will return true or false.

Example:

```
msg_values.each do |msg|
  if (SKIP_MSG_ARRAY.any? { |regular_exp| msg.match(regular_exp)})
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```